# Vuejs router with Nginx not handling correct routing

Tags: nginx, routing, configuration

I'm developing a VueJS single page application, and for local development I'm using Docker with a `docker-compose.yml` file to handle an Nginx container for the webserver and a Node container for the asset compilation.

At the moment there is a single page on the `/configurator` route where the root `/` route should redirect, and with the Vue router it works just fine: visiting `/` correctly redirects to `/configurator`.

The problem arise when refreshing the page, due Nginx not being able to handle the request since there is no appropriate file at the given uri to serve.

VueJS [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#nginx) states to set Nginx configuration `location` section as follows in order to redirect every request to the project index and therefore let Vue router to handle the navigation

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

so I made a custom `nginx.conf` file and added/renamed to the Nginx container through my `docker-compose.yml` file as below, but I still get a 404 by Nginx.

Checking from inside the Nginx container with `nginx -T` correctly list my custom file, but I noticed that `default.conf` file was the last in the list, so I tought that Nginx add additional files alphabetically, and being mine not the last one my custom config where overwritten by `default.conf`'s one, so I edited my docker-compose.yml to add it named as `z_custom.conf` just to be shure to have it as the last one, but nothing changed.

Searching online I noticed that every example I found had the custom file content identical as the default one, except for the needed customization, so I tought that I really need to entirely overwrite `default.conf` file and edit the section I need, but couldn't find any explicit indication about that.

Is that correct or there is a way to actually merge just my custom section on the entire default configuration?

##### custom.conf

```
server {
    #Vue router configuration
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

##### docker-compose.yml

```
webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./application/public:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf:ro
```

#### Update #1: adding `server_name` to custom configuration file

Following @tero-kilkanen answer I just tried adding `server_name localhost` inside `server` root section of my conf file and updated `docker-compose.yml` to copy it inside Nginx image as `localhost.conf` but nothing changed, stil getting a 404 on non-index routes.

#### Update #2

Didn't noticed before, previous update creates a conflict between default configuration and custom configuration as both files declared the same server name, so now I'm just replacing `default.conf` with my custom file, and updated `location` section as follows, but still getting 404 on non-root routes.

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Running `nginx -T` and `nginx -t` confirm that my custom config file is being read and used correctly:

```
root@be898ad4ca17:/# nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/avif                                       avif;
    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/wasm                                 wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: Please add output of `nginx -T` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to specify `server_name` in your `server` block. Then nginx will use that `server` block for your application when you request the page using the name in the URL.

Comment: Ok, but my question stand still: do I have to copy the entirety of `default.conf` or this way let me define just the `location` section?

Comment: Just tried adding `server_name localhost` inside `server` root section of my file and updated `docker-compose.yml` to copy my conf file inside Nginx images as `localhost.conf` but nothing changed.